# Windows unable to see file system of external HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

When I copy files from(or to) the external HDD to an internal one by USB 3.0 port, a disconnect happens and I get a Windows' message, that this HDD must be formatted.

Windows can't see the file system (NTFS) of the external HDD, until I cancel an interrupted copying or even I restart a Windows. When I use eSATA port, everything is well.
eSATA is on another computer.

Windows 7 x64 professional.

External HDD is

1. a standard HDD WD Green 2TB 3'' 5000x and
2. a box with Sata 2 controller and with eSATA and USB 3.0 output ports.

For my PC I was forced to buy a Renaissance controller PCI-2-USB 3.0. Renaissance Drivers are installed, newest that I could find.

Is it either a program error of Windows and can be fixed, or is it from a nonstandard hardware sequence and I have to accept this discomfort?

PS: I turned off auto-disabling of usb controllers in the power supply options, it didn't help.

Comment: you mentioned eSATA connection to another computer and that works, What OS is the other computer running?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 professional.